# Should/can anything be done about an ambiguous tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, ambiguous-tags

This tag [guard](/questions/tagged/guard) is used mainly for a command-line tool.  However, it's also used for about a few questions about [guards](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards) in functional programming.

Can we do something about this?  The concern is that, as there's currently no appropriate tag for guards in the FP sense, many questions remain untagged and so it's difficult to search for them (and the ones that are tagged get lost in the ocean of questions about the tool).  Also, the tag wiki gives no indication that the tag is used in that sense.

Comment: You might want to add that to [this list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012)... Also an up vote on an answer gives you twice the rep x_x

Comment: What do you propose to disambiguate between the two?

Comment: I would suggest creating a new, separate tag.  Is this the typical solution?